# Apache looks for files in the wrong folder

Tags: apache

Under the *htdocs* folder I have a project *project1*. The executables of the project are saved in the *build*  folder. Therefore I try to access the app by typing the following address in the browser:

```
http://<my ip address>/project1/build/
```

The problem is that it doesn't work because it looks for the js and css files at the following paths:

```
http://<my ip address>/file.js
http://<my ip address>/file.css
```

Comment: In the "asset-manifest.json" file, where all files paths are recorded, at the beginning of each path a dot is missing.

Comment: Why you do not write a regular answer then? :-)

Comment: It is also necessary to add these dots in the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

In the "asset-manifest.json" file, where all files paths are recorded, at the beginning of each path a dot is missing. And it is also necessary to add these dots in the index.html file.